# Helper in Symfony2 not able to call on Twig

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have a following Helper created in my bundle:

Edu/AccountBundle/Service/Helper.php

```
namespace Edu\AccountBundle\Service;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Edu\AccountBundle\CommonFunctions\CommonFunctions;

class Helper{

private $session;
private $router;
private $documentManager;
private $commonFunctions;

/*
 * Class:Constructor
 * @DESC:its a very first method which always called whenever this call going to be instantiate
 * @param : @session,@route,@db
 * @sunilrawat@indivar.com
 * @03-06-2016
 */
public function __construct(Session $session, Router $router, DocumentManager $dm)
{
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->dm = $dm;
    $this->commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
}

/*
 * Class:checkFinancialYearLockPeriod
 * @DESC:check a particular date on which accounts Financial Year data will be Locked So that user can not make any modifications after that
 * @param : @db
 * @sunilrawat@indivar.com
 * @03-06-2016
 */
public function checkFinancialYearLockPeriod($dm){
    $currentYearIs = $this->commonFunctions()->checkFinancialYear($this->dm);
    $exploadsCurrentYear = explode("-",$currentYearIs);
    $currentFinancialYearTo = "31-03-".$exploadsCurrentYear[1];
    return $effectiveDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+63 days", strtotime($currentFinancialYearTo)));        
}
}

 //My services.xml code is as following:
<service id="edu.account.helper" class="Edu\AccountBundle\Service\Helper">
            <argument type="service" id="session"/>
            <argument type="service" id="router"/>
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager"/>
            <tag name="twig.helper" />
        </service>     
 //So now I want to call it on Twig directly. So I am calking it as   follows:
 {{ edu.account.helper.checkFinancialYearLockPeriod() }}
```

But its not working as throwing following error:
"Variable "edu" does not exist".

Please help what is missing in this, Thanks in advance:

Comment: Yes, in my case this solution not working.. can you please assist if possible

Comment: You should add service with globals config settings to twig section in config.yml. And then call it by name from globals, not with service id

Comment: but it is also registered properly. I have checked to confirm it by running following command:
php app/console container:debug edu.account.listener its showing that is it registered.

Comment: C'mon man. Please read carefully answer to that question and what I am writing to you. Add service to twig section to globals settings in config.yml. call it from twig template by name that was given by you in that section.

Comment: twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:       
        edu.account.helper: %edu.account.helper%
Still error: 
You have requested a non-existent parameter "edu.account.helper".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113699/discussion-between-user3458514-and-denis-alimov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Helper in Symfony2 not able to call on Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606005/helper-in-symfony2-not-able-to-call-on-twig#comment62696678_37606005) 
is totally right.

There is no tag called "twig.helper". Only one called "twig.extension". If you want to use that, you should extend \Twig_Extension. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html .

But in your case, you need to do the following:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        edu_account_helper: "@edu.account.helper" #key is name in twig, value is reference to your service
```

This means in Twig-Scope, it is called "edu_account_helper". Snake-cased.

```
{{ edu_account_helper.checkFinancialYearLockPeriod() }}
```

Comment: ok let me try this one..

Comment: Thanks it working. I have made mistake in config.yml